# Validation Always Failing To Validate

Tags: javascript, validation

Tried to add in some validation to a form, but it keeps acting as if the data that is being validated is invalid, even if its valid!

```
if (document.getElementById("mileageNumber").value  == /^[0-9]+$/)
{
    if (document.getElementById("vehicleNumber").value  == /^[0-9]+$/)
    {
        <Desired Action>
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please Enter Numbers Only");
    }
}
else
{
    alert("Please Enter Numbers Only");
}
```

Can anybody see what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to test the regex and not evaluate it as a value.

```
if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(document.getElementById("vehicleNumber").value)){

    //Validation passed

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```
/^[0-9]+$/.test(document.getElementById("mileageNumber").value);
```

You can also simplify your regular expression like so: `/^\d+$/`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string with a regex object. A regex object describes a structure of a regex object. A string is just a bunch of characters. They are simply not the same thing... ever. Just like the pseudo-code `apples == carrots` will never return true, `string == regex` will never return either. It requires a function to test if a string has the structure that the regex object describes.

You can properly test a string against a regex using [`string.match( .. )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
document.getElementById("vehicleNumber").value.match( /^[0-9]+$/ );
```